# Securely creating and destroying login sessions in PHP

Tags: php, security, authentication

This is my code to control authentication on a website. I'm not sure if my logic is correct. If the username and password are correct the following happen:

```
if(session_start())
{
        session_regenerate_id(true);//without this the session ID will always be the same
        $_SESSION['loggedInUser'] = $uName;
        echo 'You are now logged in';
}
else echo 'Right password/username but session failed to start';
```

Subsequent pages check to see if the user is logged in by

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedInUser'])
{
 //rest of page
}
else echo 'you must log in';
```

When logging out I have

```
session_start();//if I don't have this the next line produces an error
session_unset();//destroys session variables
session_destroy();//ends session
```

I red not to call session_start() on logout but if I don't have it there I get the message `Trying to destroy uninitialized session`. How can I fix this?

Is it recommend or not to create a finger print based on the IP address and user agent? I red it's bad because multiple computers can share the same IP address if they are in, for example a computer lab, and all the traffic goes through a proxy and the same computer could change it's IP address if it's dynamic. On the other hand, how often does this happen? It may be worth the few blocked valid uses to prevent all session hijacking.

Even if you could recommend reputable articles I should read to learn about this topic that would be great, thanks.

5/6 answers have votes less than 0 :( Could down voters comment so I know what to look out for?

Comment: from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) `Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION`

Comment: You should re-use an existing authentication framework whenever possible, because, really, it's complex. For example, take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all you should read the [Mozilla WebAppSec Security Coding Guideline - Session Management](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAppSec/Secure_Coding_Guidelines#Session_Management) and [OWASP A3-Broken Authentication and Session Management](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A3).  You can [configure PHP's session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) to meet these requirements.

The first flaw you should prevent is [A9-Insufficient Transport Layer Protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).  In short you do not want someone to hijack a session using [a tool like Firesheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep).  This attack can be prevented by forcing the browser to only send the session id over https:

```
session.cookie_secure=1
```

You can prevent an attacker from obtaining the session id using XSS by setting the [httponly flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly):

```
session.cookie_httponly=1
```

You **always** want to use a cookie to store your session id.  If the session id can be passed using a GET or POST variable then an attacker could use [Session Fixation attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) to hijack a session.  Another way of thinking about this attack is that you don't want an attacker to create a session for another user:

```
session.use_cookies=1
session.use_only_cookies=1
```

Next you want to make sure you have atleast 128 bits of entropy from a CSPRNG.  Under *nix systems you can use `/dev/urandom`:

```
session.entropy_file="/dev/urandom"
session.entropy_length=16
```

The session handler isn't everything.  You still need to worry about [Cross-Site Request Forgery attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (aka CSRF or "Session Riding"), and Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).  XSS can be used to defeat CSRF protection (even with http_only cookies!).  [Clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) can also be used by an attacker to perform unauthorized actions.

After you set these configuration options,  just call `session_start()`. As for destroying the session call `session_destroy()` when the user logs out,  its that simple!

Comment: Cross-Site Request Forgery does not depend on sessions, as “Session Riding” may suggest. However, a user with an authenticated session is a way more valuable victim than an ‘anonymous’ user. Same applies to Clickjacking.

Comment: @Rook: I want to highlight your last paragraph! Sessions in PHP are simple to start. Always assume that there is a session cookie already existing and session data stored. Just start the session. Then look into $_SESSION and see if there are any traces of a successful login. Having a session should mean nothing on the security level. It does not prove that a user is logged in. Only the stored session data can do this.

Comment: @Gumbo: the method does not depend on sessions, but CSRF does depend on a session in the case this authentication method is implemented. Because, as you already said, an authenticated user is needed to perform a request/action using a specific URL. (just trying to make it clear for the TS).

Comment: @PENDO Well,  Gumbo is correct in the purest sense.   According to the DHS the most dangerous CSRF vulnerability (and in the top 1,000 most dangerous vulns of all time) affected Motorola surfboard cable modems.  The modem didn't create a session with the browser,  it was however only accessible on the local network.

Comment: I know, I just meant to say that CSRF indeed does not depend on sessions, but in this case it does depend on sessions. Just to make sure the author of the question does not mix things up thinking CSRF is nothing to take care of because he's using sessions

Comment: `session.entropy_*` have been removed in **PHP 7.1**, if anyone has a useful update to make to this answer.

Comment: @AymDev hmm i wonder if they finally force a proper source of entropy - this has been a disaster for years.  I am not the only one to complain.

Answer (score 1):

To securely destroy a session I would use the following code:

```
session_start();
// Unset all session values
$_SESSION = array();
// get session parameters 
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
// Delete the actual cookie.
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
// Destroy session
session_destroy();
```

In order to destroy a session you need to start it first, as you have found out it doesn't work if you don't include session_start();

The session_regenerate_id(); Function generates a new session id for the user. If used with true (session_regenerate_id(true);) then the old session id is deleted from the server when it generates a new one. The reason behind generating a new session id on every page is that it makes session hijacking much harder (Nearly Impossible?) to perform because of the users constantly changing session id.

(View PHP.net manual on [session_regenerate_id();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php))

When authenticating a user you should always check something like the IP address or Browser, these are constant things sent in the request to the server that do not change in the life time of your session, and if they do then you know something dodgy it happening. I always create two session variable one that stores the user ID so I can query a database for data, and another that stores the users password, IP address and Browser String all in one hash (sha512).

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];

// Query Database and get hashed password

$login_check = hash('sha512', $password.$ip_address.$user_browser);

if($login_check == $login_string) {
     // Logged In!!!!
     return true;
} else {
     // Not logged in
     return false;
}
```

The password is secure even though it is being stored in the session. This is because the password is hashed (Twice in this case) and because the session data is not stored on the users computer (Like cookies), it is stored in a session file.

I wrote an article on wikihow.com about secure login and authentication, is can be found [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

You can just write:

```
session_start(); // session should be started before it can be used.
```

You can assign userid of logged in member. For this you can take username and password from user input and check it in your db and return userid. For more security you can have strings for eg. "demo" and "test" just md5 both and mix it with userid in following manner.

```
$userid=md5("demo").$userid.md5("test");// you can set any string instead of demo and test.

$_SESSION['userid']=$userid;
```

While using it in other page,

```
session_start(); // If you are have not started it or included above code file in it.
```

As you know the strings while using just match it and find the exact userid from it and use it in your code.

For destroying it just use:

```
session_unset($_SESSION['userid']); // It will only unset the session userid completely.
```

Make sure that before use of any session you need to start it. In better way you can start the session in one file say init.php and include it every where where you want to use the session

Comment: Why the md5 stuff inside the session data? This only bloats the data to be moved from and to the harddisk, but because the session content is never exposed to the outside world, it does not increase any security at all. It only complicates things.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use `session_id()` to determine whether the user already got a session, if not, then use `session_start()`.

example codes from Lithium framewrok:

```
/**
 * Starts the session.
 *
 * @return boolean True if session successfully started (or has already been started),
 *         false otherwise.
 */
protected static function _start() {
    if (session_id()) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
    return session_start();
}
```

After call `_start()`, you can safely call `session_destroy()`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This question has a security tag,  and the answers should be security specific.

Answer (score 0):

To destroy a session without using "start_session()", first verify whether there is an active session of not like below

```
$existingSessionId = session_id();
if ($existingSessionId != "")
{
     // Initialize the session.
     session_start();

     // Unset all of the session variables.
     $_SESSION = array();

     // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
     // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
     if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
         $params = session_get_cookie_params();
         setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
             $params["path"], $params["domain"],
             $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
         );
     }

     // Finally, destroy the session.
     session_destroy();
}
else
{
     // No Active sessions
}
```

session_regenerate_id(true), just replace the old session id with the new one but it does not unset the old session id. This needs to be taken care by session_destroy and deleting session cookie.

Browser will send session cookie to server ever session is destroyed. PHP will get this session ID and when you do start_session(), it will use session id sent by browser. If you delete the session cookie, session_start will generate a new session id and you do not need to call session_regenerate_id()

Comment: So your code is used to destroy a session? Is that the purpose? Why bother to check if a session exists if you are just about to destroy it?

Comment: In order to use session_destroy() you need to first issue session_start() otherwise it will throw an error. As per session_destroy documentation "session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. 

In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id, then the session cookie must be deleted."

Comment: ok thanks for explaining. One more question, what does `time()-42000` do?

Comment: time()-42000 will set the cookie expiration time in the past and so browser will delete this cookie and session cookies will not be sent to server with next request