# Can I change php session parameters without php.ini and .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I am trying to change some [php session parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15596064/5978759) using `php_value` commands in .htaccess since I am using a shared server and cannot access php.ini directly.

However, it seems that the hosting server does not allow the `php_value` commands in .htaccess and they say that their php settings cannot be changed/overridden.

My question: Is there a workaround for that or do I have to change my hosting server?

Comment: [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) ?

Comment: Thanks...didn't know about that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change php.ini settings at the top of your php file using the `ini_set()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php, however your provider might be set up not to allow it for the parameters you want to set.

Include something like the following at the top of each file that users access:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1); // If you are using https

ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
```

You should do this before anything to do with sessions. It's probably worth moving this to a .inc file that is included at the top of all pages, if you don't have a file like that already that you can move them to.

You can test that the `ini_set` changes have been allowed by your provider by checking their return values, perhaps using a wrapper like:

```
function set_ini($name, $value) {
  if (!ini_set($name, $value) {
    throw new RuntimeException('ini_set failed for '.$name);
  }
}
```

(thanks to @hanshenrik for the tip about checking return value)

Comment: don't forget, a lot of webhosts blocks altering certain parameters (like 'max_execution_time'), you should always do `if(false===ini_set("foo","bar")){throw new RuntimeException('ini_set failed');}` to make sure the new settings are actually applied

Comment: Thanks...I used phpinfo() for a quick check first...It correctly sets the local settings of php overriding the master settings.