# Using Facebook social login only + php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-login

I already have people stored in my database with their email addresses. I would like to make it possible for them to click a button and log in to my website with their facebook profiles only (I don't want to manage passwords )

My guess is I use this code to retrieve an email address from facebook...
[Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

Then, check that email address against my database

Then, save something in their cookies so that they can see the pages of my site.

- Am I wrong?
- What do I store in the cookies so that it's secure?

Comment: This sounds like a job for OAuth, if you ask me. I encourage you to take a look ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you've described sounds good in general. Make sure to implement the Facebook login functionality correctly without any security flaws. Make sure you've solved all scenarios described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/testing-your-login-flow

Regarding the cookies thing: You should use [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Storing **login-related data in a cookie is a bad idea** as users can change values stored there.

If you decide to use sessions, be aware of all **security guidelines and best practices**. You can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15596064/6817376